# How is chromecast initially discovered before even connecting to wifi?

Tags: tcp, multicast, chromecast

How is chromecast initially discovered before even connecting to wifi? What is the underlying technology?

Is it done using multicast if so will a device get an ip before providing wifi password to send multicast

Answer (score 1):

https://superuser.com/questions/626199/how-does-google-chromecast-connect-to-secured-wifi

Chromecast acts as an access point when first turned on. The software you install software on your andriod, windows or mac device will find it and connect to the chromecast's AP directly. Then the chromecast scans for access points allowing you to pick one and enter in your password. Once this is done, it will connect to that access point instead of acting as it's own access point.

Comment: So, does it mean I can't setup chromecast device using a desktop which doesn't have wifi adapter?



Also is it expected a network disruption in the device which is setting up the chromecast? because it would be disconnecting from the existing access point and connecting to chromecast's ap?

Comment: I'm afraid so, you'll need to find someone with wifi device to help out